How to Enable Edit Button for Records in C# Windows Forms App using MySQL?
I'm working on a C# Windows Forms application that interacts with a MySQL database. Currently, I have implemented functionality to insert and delete records, but I'm struggling to enable editing of existing records. I have a DataGridView that displays records from the table, and I want users to be able to edit these records directly from the DataGridView.
Can someone guide me on how to implement the edit functionality? I want users to be able to click on a record in the DataGridView, make changes to it, and then save those changes back to the database when they're done. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here's a simplified version of my code:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code for inserting a new record
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code for deleting a selected record
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code for displaying records in the DataGridView
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // What code should I add here to enable editing of selected records?
    }
}

}

You can catch the cahanges with your DataGridView's DataGridView.CellValueChanged event. Then you can execute your database commands directly. Or in event handler, you can save the database commands into a collection and then with a button click event you can execute all of them at once.
This might be help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
